# Create collation in postgresql with pgadmin3

Tags: postgresql, collation

### I want set my collation in postgresql with pgadmin3:

1. how do see a list list of local collation names in Ubuntu?
2. How do I set the collation in PgAdmin-III?
3. I want set Persian collation for my database in Ubuntu

(I know how to create collation in pgadmin , but i don't know how to set this for my database?)

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by setting the collation in PgAdmin-III. Do you mean per-query collation? Do you mean encoding, not collation?\

Comment: My mean is a when you create collation in pgadmin3 with right click on Collation section , after add collation to a Collations how to set this collation for a one column or table in database.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to `CREATE COLLATION` or specify the `COLLATE` clause on a column via PgAdmin-III. That part I'm not able to help with really, I don't use PgADmin-III. Consider posting a new question with details on just that part, and tagging it `PgAdmin-III`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [list all locales on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale#List_installed_locales) you can use `locale -a`. The linked page also shows how to configure locales.

AFAIK collation support in glibc is part of the locale/encoding configuration.

You can't alter the collation of an existing database safely or easily, because indexes etc would become suddenly invalid. To set the collation when creating a new database on an existing instance of PostgreSQL use:

```
CREATE DATABASE somedb 
    TEMPLATE template0
    ENCODING = 'UTF-8' 
    LC_COLLATE = 'fa_IR' 
    LC_CTYPE='fa_IR.UTF-8';
```

You can dump your existing DB then reload to this one.

I don't recommend trying to change the default encoding / locale of a DB on Ubuntu; you'd have to `pg_dropcluster` the db, then `pg_createcluster` a new one with different settings. Just `CREATE DATABASE` with appropriate settings.

I have no idea what you mean with (2), how to "set the collation in PgAdmin-III".